# RMySQL, Shiny and PHP cloud

Tags: mysql, r, rstudio, shiny, rmysql

I'm trying to develop R shiny application using MySQL database. I'm trying to use PHP cloud and its MySQL database. And my Shiny application is in shiny cloud environment. I'm deploying my application using R Studio. So how I can connect RMySQL to MySQL database in the PHP cloud using R Studio. I tried installing RMySQL in R Studio but it gives me this error.

```
Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 1
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'RMySQL'
```

Comment: There is a nice [tutorial on installing RMySQL under Windows](http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/). Maybe it will help.

Comment: Looks like exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/24379743/2157640, but it has no answers either.

Comment: Actually I did install RMySQL in my computer. But my problem is how I'm going to connect it to cloud environment?